# Designing a random factor in a linear mxied effect model to combine repeated and single exposure datasets to prevent p-hacking

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, autoregressive, p-hacking

I currently have data that can be split into two categories: one is a repeated measures data (collected at multiple time points), whilst another is a single measure dataset (one single time point out of a set of potential timepoints). In the interest of trying to integrate the repeated measures dataset with the single measure dataset, I would like to examine if the act of repeated measures (repeated experimental exposure) would have an effect on the responses, and if it did, then show that the two datasets can not be integrated, or that they can if it was shown that there is no effect.

One solution I thought of was to construct a linear mixed effect model with the random factor taking into account the number of experiments the subject was exposed to. The idea here would be to make a random factor account both for the subject and the repeated exposure element if the subject originated from the repeated measures experiment.

So to give further context, I have two fixed effects: sex and timepoint. If I was to not account for the repeated subjects, the formula will look the following:
$ y \approx \beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot Sex+ \beta_2 \cdot Timepoint + \beta_3 \cdot Sex \cdot Timepoint + \varepsilon_i + Z_i $ where subjects is the random factor (with random intercept) encapuslated by $Z_i$. In Matlab (as that is the program I am to use), the formula for the code will look like:
fitlme(y ~ Sex * Timepoint + (1 | Subject))

As shown above, the formula for a single exposure dataset is pretty straightfoward, but I am not sure how to incoorperate the repeated portion of it. My understanding is that I need to somehow incoorperate a AR1 structure into the matrix that encodes the intra-subject variance as the AR1 matrix for repeated exposure subjects would capture the repeated measurements effect on the variance for those specific subjects, but would not do anything for single exposure subjects since their $\rho = 1$

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I do not have the option to exclude either dataset and I am concerned that I am committing statistical malpractice by inflating the number of independent samples which could then affect downstream statistics.